# IRC client with XDCC support

Tags: applications, downloading, chat, instant-messaging

Honestly, I haven't installed and checked all irc clients for Android, nevertheless I wasn't able to google any.

Does it exist?

If yes, mention it, please :)

Comment: RSS client or IRC client?

Comment: @RossC fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are some clients now.

[AndroIRC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androirc), [Yaaic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yaaic), [XdccDownloader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.playxz.xdccdownloader) and probably even more

Answer (score 0):

[CoreIRC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.aureolin.coreirc) or [IRC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.countercultured.irc4android) are the ones that currently work reliably.